# volatile and variable modification in C

Tags: c, volatile

A structure TsMyStruct is given as parameter to some functions :

```
typedef struct
{
    uint16_t inc1;
    uint16_t inc2;
}TsMyStruct;


void func1(TsMyStruct* myStruct)
{
    myStruct->inc1 += 1;
}

void func2(TsMyStruct* myStruct)
{
    myStruct->inc1 += 2;
    myStruct->inc2 += 3;
}
```

func1 is called under non-interrupt context and func2 is called under interrupt context. Call stack of func2 has an interrupt vector as origin. C compiler does not know func2 can be called (but code isn't considered as "unused" code as linker needs it in interrupt vector table memory section), so some code reading myStruct->inc2 outside func2 can be possibly optimized preventing  myStruct->inc2 to be reloaded from ram. It is true for C basic types, but is it true for inc2 structure member or some array...? Is it true for function parameters?

As a general rule, can I say "every memory zone (of basic type? or not?) modified in interrupt context and read elsewhere must be declared as volatile"?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, any memory that is used both inside and outside of an interrupt handler should be `volatile`, including structs and arrays, and pointers passed as function parameters. Assuming that you are targeting a single-core device, you do not need additional synchronization.

Still, you have to consider that `func1` could be interrupted anywhere, which may lead to inconsistent results if you're not careful. For instance, consider this:

```
void func1(volatile TsMyStruct* myStruct)
{
    myStruct->inc1 += 1;
    if (myStruct->inc1 == 4)
    {
        print(myStruct->inc1); // assume "print" exists
    }
}

void func2(volatile TsMyStruct* myStruct)
{
    myStruct->inc1 += 2;
    myStruct->inc2 += 3;
}
```

Since interrupts are asynchronous, this could print numbers different from 4. That would happen, for instance, if `func1` is interrupted after the check but before the `print` call.

Comment: you still need synchronization (even on one-processor systems).  E.g. what happens when interrupt fires in the middle (between load + store) of the `+=`?  Because synchronization usually provides an optimization barrier the `volatile` is pointless.

Comment: @ensc, visually speaking, it would seem to me that approximately 80% of my answer is dedicated to that issue.

Comment: @ensc, I think we are supposed to use atomic addition operation. I maybe wrong.

Comment: @user7176709 atomic operations work for the `+=` case.  But  `volatile` is neither enough to implement such operations nor is it needed.

Comment: @ensc, we all agree that `func1` needs to be able to operate atomically over `myStruct`. Where we don't agree is OP's unspoken context: you assume kernel development for a multi-core machine and I assume a small embedded board.

Comment: @zneak `volatile` is the wrong choice for both use cases.  Use it in simple things like `while (!flag) {}`, but not in code which is already protected by some other optimization barriers (e.g.  synchronization methods).

Answer (score 0):

no. `volatile` is not enough.  You have both to set an optimization barrier for the compiler (which **can** be `volatile`) and for the processor.  E.g. when a CPU core writes data, this can go into some cache and won't be visible for another core.

Usually, you need some locking in your code (spin locks, or mutex).  Such functions contain usually an optimization barrier so you do not need an `volatile`.

Your code is racy, with proper locking it would look like

```
void func1(TsMyStruct* myStruct)
{
    lock();
    myStruct->inc1 += 1;
    unlock();
}

void func2(TsMyStruct* myStruct)
{
    lock();
    myStruct->inc1 += 2;
    unlock();
    myStruct->inc1 += 3;
}
```

and the `lock()` + `unlock()` functions contain optimization barriers (e.g. `__asm__ __volatile__("" ::: "memory")` or just a call to a global function) which will cause the compiler to reload `myStruct`.

For nitpicking: `lock()` and `unlock()` are expected to do the right thing (e.g. disable irqs).  Real world implementations would be e.g. `spin_lock_irqsave()` + `spin_lock_irqrestore()` in linux.

Comment: Interrupt contexts are precisely one of the, like, 3 cases where volatile *is* enough.

Comment: Given "func2 is called under interrupt context", your posted code will result in a deadlock if `func1` is interrupted while it holds the lock.  Locks make interrupt handlers, and all functions at that, async-signal-**unsafe**.

Comment: @AndrewHenle why? code is an example only and the depending on the system, `lock()` can be implemented e.g. by disabling interrupts .

Comment: @zneak no; when thread `func2()` is run on a second core, changes done in core 1 might never reach it.  `volatile` is for the compiler only and does not say anything about parallel execution.